# Making changes to Magentos search result page

Tags: html, magento, search, edit

I have set up a webshop with Magento (v 1.7) and I really need to make some changes to the page which displays the search results when using the global search in the frontend.
 My first idea was looking into the `result.phtml` file that is located under `/app/design/frontend/default/myDesign/template/catalogsearch/` but all I could find there was a line which says

```
 $this->getProductListHtml()
```

I guess this function returns the string that constructs the whole search result page but I do not know where to look for the code of this function. 
Basically, I just need to add some html to each product that is displayed on that page, nothing complex really - but the whole data structure of Magento got me a bit confused there.
For which file in which folder would I have to look in order to modify the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the appearance of the products, you will need to change `/app/design/frontend/default/myDesign/template/catalog/product/list.phtml.`
Please note that this template is also used for category pages.